# istream operator skips space characters

Tags: c++

```
void transferData(ifstream& input_file, ofstream& output_file)
{
    char ch;
    while (input_file >> ch) {
        if ((ch >= 97 && ch <= 118) || (ch >= 65 && ch <= 86)) {
            ch += 4;
            output_file << ch;
        }
        else if ((ch >= 87 && ch <= 90) || ch >= 119 && ch <= 122) {
            ch -= 22;
            output_file << ch;
        }
        else if (ch == 32) {
                output_file << '\t';
        }
        else
            output_file << ch;

    }
}
```

The code works, but it does not add spaces between the words in the output file. What is the reason for that?

```
Input: "This text is to test the program."
Output: "Xlmwxibxmwxsxiwxxlitvskveq."
```

Comment: `input_file >> ch` skips whitespace. Go back to your earlier version: `input_file.get(ch)`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `std::noskipws`.

```
while (input_file >> std::noskipws >> ch)
```

By default the streams skip white space before reading into a variable. This is somewhat of a hangover from C scanf() functions (which skipped white space before reading into a variable).

Note: This is a property of the `operator>>`.

You can also use iterators to do the job:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator loop(input_file);
std::istreambuf_iterator end;

for(;loop != end; ++loop) {
   ch = *loop;
   // STUFF
}
```

If you have C++20 we can make that look nicer with a range based loop:

```
// Note I don't have a C++20 compiler so sort of guessing based on API.
for(char ch: std::ranges::range(std::istreambuf_iterator loop(input_file), std::istreambuf_iterator{}) {
     // STUFF
}
```